# How would I import a module within an npm package subfolder with webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack, babeljs

Lets say theres a package in `node_modules` called foo and I want to import a module within a library such as `foo/module` via webpack & babel...

`import Foo from 'foo';` works

`import SomeOtherModule from 'foo/module';` fails with the following:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'foo/module' in
>   /Users/x/Desktop/someproject/js

Which makes make it seem like webpack is looking for the file in the wrong place instead of `node_modules`

My webpack.config looks like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill','./js/script.js'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './build/script.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'

};
```

Comment: Show file and folder structure for foo module, please

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It should work with `import 'foo/module';`. It will resolve file `./node_modules/foo/module.js` or `./node_modules/foo/module/index.js` and **not** something like `./node_modules/foo/node_modules/module/index.js` if it expected (in that case you better to install module via npm).

Comment: structure for the module is `./node_modules/foo/module/index.js` which doesnt resolve

Comment: I checked in test project and it worked, when I rename ./node_modules/foo/module/index.js  to ./node_modules/foo/module/index1.js , run webpack, it says "Cannot resolve module 'foo/module' in /home/user/www/so-2/js". So, maybe you have typo in filename?

Comment: oh you're right, the module foo has a folder `src` so `import from foo/src/module` worked thanks

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko Is there a way to import via `import 'foo/module';` a `module.js`file  if the file itself has the following path: `foo/src/module.js`? I don't want the `src/` subdirectory to be in the path when importing...

Comment: @tonix You can try to add alias: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/ , something like `foo: "foo/src"`

Comment: Will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: for me worked 
`const { ValidationError } = require('graphql-schema-linter/lib/validation_error')`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom path using the `module` attribute in your `package.json`. Example:

```
{
  ...
  "module": "dist/mylib.min.js",
  ...
}
```

See [What is the "module" package.json field for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708484/what-is-the-module-package-json-field-for)

Comment: "... Node.js ignored (and still ignores) the top-level "module" field." (source:https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_dual_commonjs_es_module_packages) - they very much seem to not want to support this additional field inside package.json