# What is the "module" package.json field for?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I've seen some npm packages ([vue for example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.2.2/package.json#L6)) have a `module` field in their package.json.

But [`module` is not included in the package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json) - is this a convention of some kind? Is there documentation for this somewhere?

Comment: convention for ECMAScript modules - here's a good read on the different approaches to identifying ESM's: https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e#.4o5p6pq73

Answer (score 206, accepted):

### Update: April 2022

The `module` field is not officially defined by Node.js and support is not planned. Instead, the Node.js community settled on [package exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) which they believe is more versatile.

For practical reasons JavaScript bundlers will continue to support the `module` field. The esbuild docs [explain](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#main-fields) when to use `module` as well as related fields `main` and `browser`.

### Original Answer

> Is  `"module"` an official npm property or is this a convention of some kind?

It's a [proposal](https://github.com/dherman/defense-of-dot-js/blob/master/proposal.md), but likely to be supported due to de facto usage.

> Is there documentation for this somewhere?

There is, in fact, and it can be found [right here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/4217dca299d89c8c18ac44c878b5fe9581974ef3/002-es6-modules.md#51-determining-if-source-is-an-es-module) and later removed [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es-modules.md).

> What's it for?

ES6 Module Interoperability in Node. Additional discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/issues/13) and [here](https://github.com/jsforum/jsforum/issues/5). And here's [a blog post](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c) from Rich Harris talking more about it.

Comment: Does WebPack have documentation on this somewhere, or just Rollup?

Comment: Looks like they have added it here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#final-steps

Comment: This never got implemented. Instead they have the `type` field that can be set to `"module"`.

Answer (score 78):

This is used by bundler tools for ESM (ECMAScript Module) detection. The [Rollup documentation](https://rollupjs.org/#compatibility) says it pretty well:

> If your `package.json` file also has a `module` field, ES6-aware tools
>   like [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) and [webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org/) will [import the ES6 module version](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) directly.

[This article on Rollup 1.0](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-splitting-for-libraries-bundling-for-npm-with-rollup-1-0-2522c7437697#9f6f) says it another way:

> The `main` field makes sure that Node users using `require` will be served the UMD version. The `module` field is not an official npm feature but a common convention among bundlers to designate how to import an ESM version of our library.

Further discussion of `pkg.module` is on the [Rollup Github Wiki](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) and the [webpack Docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#final-steps).

Comment: Should `main` be a minified version of UMD version of the library? Or should it be an unminified one? What about `module`? I guess that module should not be minified because the user will use its bundler (Webpack, Parcel, etc...) and by using the source file with ES6 module exports the bundler can laverage tree-shaking, correct?