# Check to see if dynamic import is a module in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, eval, es6-modules

I am working on a ScriptManager class for a project that was created many years ago.  The original code read scripts from a database, and these scripts are different depending on the customer and installation (the application is a desktop app that uses Chrome Embedded Framework to display web pages).  The code would read custom JavaScript code and eval() it, which of course is highly undesirable.

I am replacing this code with a ScriptManager class that can support dynamically inserted code, and the ScriptManager is capable of loading code as a module using JavaScript's dynamic import() command, or loading code as pure script by creating a script tag dynamically in the document.

My problem is that there are many different possible custom code blocks in the database, and not all are modules; some will be pure script until those can be converted to modules at a later time.  My code can handle this as described above, but I need a way to detect if the script code from the database is a module, so I can either use the import() command or insert a script tag if it is not.

I am solving this temporarily by making sure any module script code has "export const isModule = true", and checking this after calling import().  This works, but any code that is pure script still results in a module variable, but with no exports in it.  If possible I don't want the other developers to have to remember to add isModule = true to any modules they develop in the future.

Is there a way to check that code is a module without having to do complex analysis of the code to check if there are exports in it?  Since import() still returns an object and throws no errors if there are no exports, I don't know how to detect this.

UPDATE:  Here are some examples of how this is intended to work:

```js
// Not real code, pretend that function gets the string of the script.
let code = getSomeCodeFromTheDatabase();

// Save the code for later loading.
let filename = 'some-filename.js';
saveCodeToFile(code, filename);

// Attempt to dynamically import the script as a module.
let module = await import(filename);

// If it is NOT a module, load it instead as a script tag.
// This is where I need to be able to detect if the code is
// a module or pure script.
if (!module.isModule) {
  let scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.src = filename;
  
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Honestly its not that easy to tell, if you don't know how they are configured to be resolved as a particular type of module. You also have differn't means for packaging a JavaScript/TypeScript project, which complicates the topic further. I added an answer below, and tried to include the most helpful info I could. Contemporary JS is beging to require that JS-Developers have a good understanding of the JavaScript Module system, what modules are out their, how they work, and how to know what one looks like.

Comment: Also, if you showed me an example of a dynamic import that you wanted to infer the module type from, I may be able to offer more help.

Comment: Just store for each code in the database whether it's a script or a module. You cannot detect it - there is no difference - if the code doesn't use `import` or `export` declarations.

Comment: If you have so many code blocks that you need a database, surely you have used some sort of module system previously, right? The scripts don't expect to run in the global scope and be able to declare global variables, do they? Most standalone snippets should in fact work just fine being loaded (wrongly) as a module.

Comment: @Bergi - The older version of the app was a desktop app with an IE embedded browser, with ES3 as the highest supported JS, so no modules.  We are converting it to Chromium Embedded Framework targeting ESNext for both TypeScript code and Module resolution.  All the existing code was not in module, and is being converted over time.  So yes - a lot of messy global variables and no modules, but that's exactly what I am changing.  For now it needs to support older non-module scripts.

Comment: @j D3V - The type of module will always be the same, module resolution is ESNext in our tsconfig.json.  This is a standalone desktop app that uses Chromium Embedded Framework, so we have no need to worry about other browser versions or support.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that there are no export after import. In chrome `import()` added empty `default` for non module.

```
function isNotModule(module) {
    return (!Object.keys(module).length) || (!!module.default && typeof module.default === 'object' && !Object.keys(module.default).length)
}
```

```
import('./test.js')
    .then((module) => {
        console.log('./test.js',isNotModule(module))
    })
```

May be it's better to check source code via regex to check if it contains `export`

something like this

```
const reg = new RegExp('([^\w]|^)export((\s+)\w|(\s*{))')
reg.test(source)
```

Comment: Well, the module doesn't have a default export, so module.default is undefined whether it's a module or not, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Please tell me the version of chrome framework.  Using import() in chrome adds defaults as an empty object for a non-module.
So if defaults can be undefined code can be changed. update example

Comment: The Chromium version being used is 96.0.4664.110.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't add any default.

Answer (score 0):

So if you look here [How can I tell if a particular module is a CommonJS module or an ES6 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960799/how-can-i-tell-if-a-particular-module-is-a-commonjs-module-or-an-es6-module/72519902#72519902) you will see I answered a similar question.

So the thing is Sarah, modules are defined by the way that they resolve. Module-types resolving differently is what, not only makes them incompatible with one another, but it is also why we name them differently. Originally Transpillers like **Babel** & **TypeScript** were invented because of differences in ECMA-262 Specifications, and the desire to support people who didn't have the updated specifications, as well as supporting the newer features for those who did.

Today transpilers are still being used, conceptually, much the same way. They still help us maintain a single code base while supporting older specifications, and features in newer specifications, at the same time, but the also have the added benefit of being able to generate multiple different builds from a single code base. They use this to support different module types. In node.js, the primary module-type is CJS, but the future lies in ESM modules, so package maintainers have opted to dual build the projects. The use the TypeScript Compiler *(aka Transpiler)* to emit a CJS build, and an ESM build.

Now this is where things get complicated, because you cannot tell just by looking at a module if it CJS or ESM in this situation, **you absolutely have to inspect its code, and check if it has more than one `tsconfig.json` file (because it would need at-least 2 to maintain a bi-modular build (which are becoming increasingly common with the turn of each day)

#### My Suggestion to You:

**Use well documented packages.** Good packages should be documented well, and those packages should state in their `README.md` document, what type of package/module they are, and if the package supports more than one module type. If in doubt you can either come and ask here, or better yet, you can ask the maintainer by creating an issue, asking them to add that information to their `README.md` document.

Comment: I  this particular case, the code in question is a desktop app using Chrome Embedded Framework, which means we have complete control over what is supported.  Our tsconfig.json specifies ESNext as the module code generation. Modules haven't  been used up until this point - it's in the process of being converted to TypeScript and CEF from the original which used an IE embedded browser (and ES3 as the highest supported JS code).