# How to determine if NPM package implements ES5 or ES6 modules?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

How to determine if NPM package supports ES5 or ES6 type of module ?

Comment: For node.js packages, just see whether they use the `.mjs`  extension. You can also [look at the package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708484/1048572)

Comment: You can check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/are-you-es5

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer with certainty, because it requires parsing JS -- a notoriously difficult problem.

If you're okay with a solution that gives the right answer most of the time -- I have a build system which transpiles ESMs with Babel in a mixed CommonJS/ESM environment with automatic dependency discovery.  How I figure out if a given file is ESM or not is

```
egrep '^\s*import\s+.*\sfrom\s+' "$filename"
```

There are obvious situations where this will false-trigger, but it has served me well.