# My React component on npm can't be found when consumers run tests against it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, jestjs, node-modules

I'm rather new to the world of NPM package publishing, but I have a small reusable React component that I published a while back, and recently I updated that package to a new major version by implementing Typescript support. It seems to work pretty well; however, a user of the package has reported that when trying to run their Jest tests after importing the component into a fresh `create-react-app` application, Jest claims that it can't find the component's existence.

Example: User installs `my-package` from NPM into their CRA app, and changes their `App.js` thus:

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import MyComponent from "my-component";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            Hello World
            <MyComponent someProp="somePropValue" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

They also create a test thus:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("renders App component", () => {
    render(<App />);
    const element = screen.getByText(/Hello World/i);
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Running this test (with `npm run test`) blows up with the following error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'my-component' from 'src/App.js'

    Require stack:
      src/App.js
      src/App.test.js
```

Googling this error message leads to a lot of people talking about setting up `ts-config.json` or `ts-jest` in the consuming project, but I don't recall ever having to do this when installing other people's packages in my own projects. So I feel like this is possibly a problem with my package's configuration instead. I would appreciate any insight on what I might have done wrong in setting it up.

Here is the package.json file for my package:

```
{
    "name": "react-multivalue-text-input",
    "version": "2.2.0",
    "description": " A text input component for React which maintains and displays a collection of entered values as an array of strings.",
    "module": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "prepare": "husky install",
        "dev": "node src/dev/serve.js",
        "clean": "rimraf dist",
        "build": "npm run clean && node src/dev/build.js && tsc",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint src/",
        "validate": "run-s test lint",
        "docs:serve": "npx styleguidist server",
        "docs:build": "npx styleguidist build",
        "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/dom": "^8.13.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.1.1",
        "@types/jest": "^27.5.0",
        "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.21.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.21.0",
        "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
        "commitizen": "^4.2.4",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "css-tree": "^2.3.1",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
        "esbuild": "^0.14.38",
        "esbuild-css-modules-plugin": "^2.6.3",
        "eslint": "^8.14.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.1",
        "jest": "^28.0.3",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.0.2",
        "live-server": "^1.2.2",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "react-docgen-typescript": "^2.2.2",
        "react-styleguidist": "^11.2.0",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "ts-jest": "^28.0.1",
        "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
        "typescript": "^4.6.4",
        "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.72.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.0.8",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "config": {
        "commitizen": {
            "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my build script:

```
const { build } = require('esbuild');
const cssModulesPlugin = require('esbuild-css-modules-plugin');
const { dependencies } = require('../../package.json');

const entryFile = 'src/index.tsx';
const shared = {
    bundle: true,
    entryPoints: [entryFile],
    // Treat all dependencies in package.json as externals to keep bundle size to a minimum
    external: Object.keys(dependencies),
    logLevel: 'info',
    minify: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    plugins: [cssModulesPlugin()]
};

build({
    ...shared,
    format: 'esm',
    outfile: './dist/index.js',
    target: ['esnext', 'node12.22.0']
});
```

ANd here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.test.ts",
        "**/*.test.tsx",
        "**/*.spec.tsx",
        "src/dev/dev.tsx",
        "src/build/build.tsx"
    ]
}
```

Is there any obvious reason why this sort of configuration would lead to this un-smooth user experience on the package consumer's side? I would appreciate any guidance to point me in the right direction. (Alternatively, is this somehow a normal experience when consuming Typescript packages, and not a problem on my side?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `package.json` file misses the [`"main"`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#main) field from [`v2.0.0`](https://github.com/blackjackkent/react-multivalue-text-input/blob/v2.0.0/package.json#L5), but was correctly [present before](https://github.com/blackjackkent/react-multivalue-text-input/blob/a8a3a87318f6be57ecc3aa231f15581e67c0c813/package.json#L6).

> If `main` is not set it defaults to `index.js` in the package's root folder.

You now have a `"module"` field instead, that links to your package entry point, but not all tools support it. See [What is the "module" package.json field for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708484/what-is-the-module-package-json-field-for)