# I get the "default is not a constructor" error when trying to use `glidejs`

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, glidejs

I have the following code:

```
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide";

const SectionSlider = () => {
const UNIQUE_CLASS = "random_string"
let MY_GLIDEJS = useMemo(() => {
    return new Glide(`.${UNIQUE_CLASS}`, {
      perView: itemPerRow,
      gap: 32,
      bound: true,
      breakpoints: {
        1280: {
          perView: itemPerRow - 1,
        },
        1024: {
          gap: 20,
          perView: itemPerRow - 1,
        },
        768: {
          gap: 20,
          perView: itemPerRow - 2,
        },
        640: {
          gap: 20,
          perView: itemPerRow - 3,
        },
        500: {
          gap: 20,
          perView: 1.3,
        },
      },
    });
  }, [UNIQUE_CLASS]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      MY_GLIDEJS.mount();
    }, 100);
  }, [MY_GLIDEJS, UNIQUE_CLASS]);

return (
    <div className={`${UNIQUE_CLASS} flow-root`}>
    ...
    </div>
)};
```

When rendering this component it throws this error:

```
TypeError: _glidejs_glide__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default is not a constructor
```

Additionally the packages I am using (related with this issue) are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/glidejs__glide": "^3.6.0",
```

What is my mistake exactly?

Comment: Which version of Glide are you using?

Comment: @Phil I updated the question including the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Glide uses the now defunct `module` declaration (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817320/283366)).

From their [`package.json`](https://github.com/glidejs/glide/blob/master/package.json#L9)

> ```json
> "module": "dist/glide.esm.js",
> ```

According to [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#final-steps), this should still work but something else seems wrong. I'd try [raising a bug](https://github.com/glidejs/glide/issues/new).

To work around this for now, you can use the following

```js
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm" // may need ".js"
```

Note that `@types/glidejs__glide` only defines types for:

- `dist/glide.js`, and
- `dist/glide.modular.esm.js`

Comment: This is giving me the warning: 1Could not find a declaration file for module `@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.esm.js'.`, but even if I still run it, there doesn't seem to be a change, I still get the exact same error. But if this is not a mistake on my code maybe I should create an issue with them.

Comment: Are you using Typescript? Your question is tagged [tag:javascript] so I didn't think that would be an issue

Comment: Yes I am, I completely forgot to add that tag!!!

Comment: Might be time to find a new, modern carousel library

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. It's probably the same for "react-dates" which I also chose for some reason.

Comment: @dearn44 I found the TS problem. There's no type definitions for `glide.esm.js`. Have updated my answer

Comment: I'm afraid that both with and without the`.js` ending, its the exact same error message.

Comment: Note that I changed it from `dist/glide.esm.js` to `dist/glide.modular.esm.js`. Only the latter has type definitions

Comment: FYI it works fine for me in a Node `"type": "module"` build. Haven't tried with Webpack yet but that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Correct. Images are not switching at all, but at least the website can render now. That's a start and a reason to use some other slider.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the navigations of the images work for you

```
import Glide, { Controls, Breakpoints } from '@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm'
```

When mounting your Glide instance pass these additional parameters to enable controls

```
new Glide('.glide').mount({ Controls, Breakpoints })
```

You can find reference at https://glidejs.com/docs/setup/