# Import from subfolder of npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, package.json

I've been working on creating a small library of React components for use in several other projects. I am publishing the package internally (using a private GitHub repository) and then including in another project. However, when I go to import from a subdirectory of the package I am not able to do so as the paths don't match.

The projects using the package all utilize webpack to bundle/transpile code as I am trying to avoid doing **any** building in the component library if possible.

### Directory Structure

```
- package.json
- src/
  - index.js
  - Button/
    - index.js
    - Button.jsx
    - ButtonGroup.jsx
  - Header/
    - index.js
    - Header.jsx (default export)
```

**package.json**

```
...
"main": "./src/index.js",
"scripts": "",
...
```

**src/Button/index.js**

```
import Button from './Button';
import ButtonGroup from './ButtonGroup';

export default Button;

export { Button, ButtonGroup};
```

**src/index.js**

Is this file actually necessary if only importing from subdirectories?

```
import Button from './Button';
import ButtonGroup from './Button/ButtonGroup';
import Header from './Header';

export { Button, ButtonGroup, Header };
```

**Other Project**

```
// This project is responsible for building/transpiling after importing
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'components-library/Button';
```

### Example

[Material-UI](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) is a library of React components that is used by requiring in the following fashion: `import { RadioButtonGroup } from 'material-ui/RadioButton`. I've tried to figure out how this works for them but to no avail yet.

### Similar Questions

- [How would I import a module within an npm package subfolder with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823654/how-would-i-import-a-module-within-an-npm-package-subfolder-with-webpack)

  - This is very nearly the correct approach I require, except that the import path used there involved the `src/` directory, which I am trying to avoid (should be `component-library/item`, not `component-library/src/item` (which does work currently though))
- [Publishing Flat NPM Packages](https://davidwells.io/blog/publishing-flat-npm-packages-for-easier-import-paths-smaller-consumer-bundle-sizes)

  - This is exactly what I want except that I was hoping to not have a "build" phase in the package (rely on importing locations to build/transpile)

### Questions

1. Can I skip the `src/` directory somehow in the import path?
2. Can I skip any type of build phase in the package (so developers don't have to build before committing)?
3. How does a package similar to material-ui handle this?

Comment: Did you discover how `Material-UI` achieves the `import npm-package/subfolder/Component` way to import a `src/subfolder/Component` component?

Comment: I eventually moved on from this to other alternatives, sorry.

Comment: Could you share your experience, please? I'm currently looking for something similar and couldn't find useful resources. Right now I am packing a library I'm writing without the `src` directory (https://github.com/tonix-tuft/react-js-utl). I create subfolders with ES6 source code in the root of the project and publish those dirs to NPM, but I guess this is not optimal (e.g. ES6 exports do not work server-side in Node)... This way though, I am able to import the needed files using the `react-js-utl/subfolder` syntax. By the way, I wish you a happy new year! Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not remember what I wound up doing, as it has been almost a year and a half :(. I do wish there were resources on this, but do remember that I wasn't able to figure it out soon enough and had to move on.

Comment: you can this my anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/61829655/8079868

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Can I skip the src/ directory somehow in the import path?

Yes. Using the package.json `"exports"` field, which should be supported by Webpack in a near future (see this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9509)), but has already been supported by Node since Node 12 LTS following the [Bare Module Specifier Resolution proposal](https://github.com/jkrems/proposal-pkg-exports/):

**package.json**

```
...
"main": "./src/index.js",
"type": "module",
...
"exports": {
  "./Button": "./src/Button/index.js",
  "./Header": "./src/Header/index.js"
},
...
```

Now, the following code:

```js
// This project is responsible for building/transpiling after importing
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'components-library/Button';
```

should be translated to:

```js
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'components-library/src/Button/index.js';
```

which should correctly import the requested modules.

#### Caveat

Now, it would certainly be tempting to try a simpler version like:

```
...
"exports": {
  "./Button": "./src/Button/",
  "./Header": "./src/Header/"
},
...
```

so as the usual import statement

```js
import { ... } from 'components-library/Button';
```

gets translated to

```js
import { ... } from 'components-library/src/Button';
```

This looks nice, but **it will not work** in this case, because your submodules don't have each their own `package.json` file but rely on their `index.js` file to be found.

> **/!\ Unlike in CommonJS, there is no automatic searching for index.js or index.mjs or for file extensions.**

---

#### src/index.js - Is this file actually necessary if only importing from subdirectories?

I don't think so, but you can keep it if you want.

---

#### Can I skip any type of build phase in the package?

Using the `"exports"` field does not require you to transpile your code.

Comment: Good answer. I found more information here: https://medium.com/swlh/npm-new-package-json-exports-field-1a7d1f489ccf

Comment: Typescript users: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079

Comment: Excellent answer! I just came back to this (years later!) with a similar requirement, and was happy to see this answer, as I did not realize `exports` could use multiple files!

Answer (score 2):

The answer may depend on how you installed your components library.  If you did it via either `npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>` or `npm install <git repo url>`,

1. You should be able to `import {Button} from 'component-library/Button'` as is, according to [your first linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830919/6571327). Similar to [Node's require() resolution](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), Webpack should resolve subdirectories within component-library relative to component-library's entry point. You can find the docs on customizing the resolution behavior via the [webpack.config.resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) property. [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/) seems to rely on resolving subdirectory imports from the module entry directory.
2. To distribute an ES module library, there's no need for building before distribution.  However, projects such as [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify) may need a pre-transpiled version.

Alternately, you can write `import {Button} from 'components-library'`. 
 Webpack will trace the dependencies back through each `index` without a fuss.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions there is webpack aliasing system.
You can create another project, call it for example 'app-aliases', so your aliases will be reusable.
This project will has one js file with all of your packages paths:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
'@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/components-library/src'),
'@another': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/any/path/you/want'),
}
```

And then add it to the webpack configuration in any project which will be responsible for building/transpiling:
webpack.config.js

```
const appAliases = require('app-aliases');

const config = {
...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...appAlises
    }
  }
}
```

In the runtime code you will be able to use it like this:

```
import {Button} from '@components/Button';
import {Something} from '@another'
```

If you are using typescript you will need to add the same aliases to the `paths` tsconfig property.
So answers to your questions are:

1. Yes, you can use any path in aliases
2. Yes, it is not necessary to build all of your projects
3. I see that now mui uses imports from directi packages (core for example), see https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/ there is `import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';`. But I hope they using re-export that I described below.

Also about `node.js` resolution mechanism.
When you import some library it tries to find `node_modules/some-library/package.json` and then `main` property inside it. This property should lead to your main entry point. Usually it is `src/index.js` (you should set it in package.json if it is no there yet). In this file you can re-export anything you want from internals file structure and will be able to use it without the full path.
Please see this [repo](https://github.com/nickbullock/node-reexport-example) for some examples.

Comment: I can't take the time to verify this in the context of the original answer (since I no longer have the project); however, it does appear to match what I now know about Webpack aliases, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'am an angular developer never used react but what I could tell that material-ui are using monorepo where same concept exists in angular where we create one workspace and this workspace hold multiple project/packages as named in react. for more info [Workspaces with Yarn](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/yarn-workspaces-organize-project-codebase-pro/)

Material-ui using fake paths in tsconfig to make it appears like src folder doesn't exists this from the git you provided: [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/tsconfig.json)

Comment: Does this answer address the user's question? You may want to bring your skills and experience to questions tagged with angular.

Comment: Yes, If you follow my answer you could create a project with the same structure as martial-ui project. What they did is a workspace containing multiple packages this is called monorepo project structure. second part of the question where you could import you packages as import { componentName} from '@company/workspaceName' this is done in tsconfig.json and gave him the axcample from material-ui as follow: 
"paths": {
      "@material-ui/core": ["./packages/material-ui/src"],
      "@material-ui/core/*": ["./packages/material-ui/src/*"],
      ....
}
this is called creating fake path.

Answer (score 1):

you have to install **[babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)** package

Specify the package relative path in your **.babelrc** file alias like this

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "components-library": "./node_module/components-library"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

then you can import subdir of npm package like this

```
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from 'components-library/Button';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but requires publishing a curated `dist` folder rather then the root of your project.

The whole thing is rather simple if you understand how module resolution works, and you just need a small script to prepare your distribution.

Lest I repeat all the details here, please see my answer for [Importing from subfolders for a javascript package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537252/1179377).