# Importing from subfolders for a javascript package

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollup

I have a typescript library consists of multiple folders. Each folder contains an index.ts file which exports some business logic. I am trying to bundle this with rollup to achieve this behavior on the call site:

```js
import { Button, ButtonProps } from 'my-lib/button'
import { Input, Textarea } from 'my-lib/input'
import { Row, Column } from 'my-lib/grid'
```

This is the directory structure:

[image]

I have a main `index.ts` under `src/` which contains:

```js
export * from './button';
export * from './input';
export * from './grid';
```

With this style, I can do:

```js
import { Button, Input, InputProps, Row, Column } from 'my-lib'
```

But I don't want this. I want to access to each module by their namespaces. If I remove exports from the `index.ts` file, all I can do is:

```js
import { Button } from 'my-lib/dist/button'
```

which is something I didn't see before. Adding `dist/` to the import statement means I am accessing the modules via a relative path. I want `my-lib/Button`.

I am using rollup. I tried to use `alias` plugin but didn't work. Below is my rollup config:

```js
const customResolver = resolve({
  extensions: ['ts'],
});

export default {
  input: `src/index.ts`,
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      // plugins: [terser()],
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true,
      plugins: [terser()],
    },
  ],
  // Indicate here external modules you don't wanna include in your bundle (i.e.: 'lodash')
  external: [],
  watch: {
    include: 'src/**',
  },
  plugins: [
    // Allow json resolution
    json(),
    // Compile TypeScript files
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    // Allow bundling cjs modules (unlike webpack, rollup doesn't understand cjs)
    commonjs(),
    // Allow node_modules resolution, so you can use 'external' to control
    // which external modules to include in the bundle
    // https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve#usage
    resolve(),

    // Resolve source maps to the original source
    sourceMaps(),
    alias({
      entries: [
        { find: 'my-lib/button', replacement: './dist/button' },
        { find: 'my-lib/input', replacement: './dist/input' },
        { find: 'my-lib/grid', replacement: './dist/grid' },
      ],
      customResolver,
    }),
  ],
};
```

And this is the `tsconfig` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ES6",
    "lib": ["ES2017", "ES7", "ES6", "DOM"],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "my-lib/button": ["./src/button"],
      "my-lib/input": ["./src/input"],
      "my-lib/grid": ["./src/grid"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I don't know how to achieve the same structure as `lodash/xxx` or `material-ui/yyy` with rollup.

People suggest aliases or named exports but I couldn't make it work.

The closest thing to my problem is below question:

[Import from subfolder of npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345257/import-from-subfolder-of-npm-package)

I want to achieve the same thing but with `typescript` and `rollup`.

I think I am missing something, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the only difference between

```
import { Button } from 'my-lib/dist/button'
```

and

```
import { Button } from 'my-lib/button'
```

is just one more directory level.

Once said that, until you have `"outDir": "dist",` in your `tsconfig.json` file you need to add `dist/` to your `import` statements.

Indeed, both the libraries you taken as example are distributed with files in the root directory: [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) directly has `js` files in the root, while [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/tsconfig.json) has not `outDir` option in its `tsconfig.json` file (which means to write output files to root directory).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me make sure If I understand correctly: when I installed my library on another project the whole import process relies on the relative paths? There is no magic behind the scenes because of the bundlers? 

What about those packages like

- https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/alias
or
- https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver

I thought these packages provide this functionality without moving the files to the root level.

Comment: No, there is no magic behind the scenes @alix . There are some differences between `import {} from "./path"` and `import {} from "path"` ; I assumed you know about them. I'm not a master with these two packages but it seems they add some magic to import a local library with the second `import` form. To clarify: how your library (`my-lib`) is installed on other project? Is it through `npm` or some other custom way?

Comment: Yes, it will be installed via npm. This is not my first npm package. I am familiar with the process but this is the first time I tried to implement `import from subfolder` thing. That's why I am confused. I didn't think that "I move the bundled files to the root dir and bingo"

Comment: Yes @alix , that's all. So, if you are using rollup with only this specific purpose, probably you no longer need it.

Comment: I see. Let me try your way and I will back and release the bounty. Grazie!

Comment: OK. You are right, I installed the `lodash` and the `material-ui` packages and inspect them under `node_modules`. They put every sub-module into the root level. That's what I am going to do. To keep my library repository clean, I will create a `post-install` script so those bundled files will be moved to the root level only when the user installs my package. Thanks again!

Comment: I can't release the bounty award for the next 3 hours. We have to wait.

Comment: We can wait for 3 hours :) thank you. Happy I have been useful!

Answer (score 28):

This is possible, but requires some extra steps. A mentioned above, this is the approach taken by Material-UI.

The trick is to publish a curated `dist` folder, rather the root folder of your repo.

## Building

To begin with, let's just be clear that it doesn't matter whether your library is built using CommonJS or ESM. This is about **module resolution**.

Let's assume the project is called `my-package`.

Now most projects, after we have built `src/` to `dist/` will have

```
my-package
  package.json
  src/
    index.js
  dist/
    index.js
```

and in package.json

```
"main": "dist/index.js"
```

or for esm

```
"module": "dist/index.js"
```

## Publishing

Most projects just add `.npmignore` and publish the root of the project, so when installed the project ends up in `node_modules` like so:

```
node_modules
  my-package/
    package.json
    dist/
      index.js
```

## Resolving

Once installed, consider this import:

```
import myProject from "my-project";
```

The module resolver will do this (simplifying greatly, as the [full algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) is irrelevant here):

- Go to `node_modules`
- Find `my-project`
- Load `package.json`
- Return the file in `main` or `module`

Which will work because we have

```
node_modules
  my-package/
    package.json
    dist/
      index.js
```

## Resolving subpaths

```
import something from "my-project/something";
```

The resolution algorithm will work with

```
node_modules
  my-project/
    somthing.js
```

also with

```
node_modules
  my-project/
    something/
      index.js
```

and with

```
node_modules
  my-project/
    something/
      package.json
```

where in the latter case it will again look at `main` or `module`.

But we have:

```
node_modules
  my-package/
    package.json
    dist/
      index.js
```

## The Trick

The trick is, instead of publishing your project root with its `dist` folder, to "frank" the `dist` folder and publish the `dist` folder using `npm publish dist` instead.

Frank (as in *frank a letter*) means you need to create a `package.json` in your `dist` folder; add `README.md` `LICENSE` etc.

A fairly short example of how this is done can be found [here](https://github.com/Izhaki/regraph/blob/e73bf94e622ef5a6d29530ae872aaa1c8575e7ca/scripts/frank-dist.js).

So, given we had after build:

```
node_modules
  my-package/
    package.json
    dist/
      index.js
      something.js
```

Once published we get

```
node_modules
  my-project/
    package.json
    index.js
    something.js
```

Where `package.json` is the curated one.

Comment: Hey, that made a lot of sense to me. One question is how do you approach developing the library locally together with the consumer module using npm link? In that case, the imports would not work because we would have the original source code structure instead of the distributed one at the top-level.

Comment: Good question. You should run the `npm link` in the `dist` folder, not the root. Makes sense?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The custom dist folder approach worked. Worth mentioning is that simply copying your existing package.json will not work as expected if you rely on lots of `pre*` and `post*` scripts to run when doing `npm publish`, as they will have PWD set to your `dist` folder, instead of your root folder! Here's one of the fixup commits I had to do: https://github.com/fatso83/retry-dynamic-import/commit/4c8dbe2cc319daa76db1bb97c69affb10b759e8b

Answer (score 4):

After numerous trials and errors, I was able to get this working by passing in a list of inputs, using the  [preserveModules](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpreservemodules) and [preserveModulesRoot](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpreservemodulesroot) options, and a simple postinstall script.

Here's my **rollup.config.js**

```
const options = {
  input: [
    'src/index.ts',
    'src/api/index.ts',
    'src/components/index.ts',
    'src/contexts/index.ts',
    'src/hooks/index.ts',
    'src/lib/index.ts',
    'src/types/index.ts',
    'src/utils/index.ts',
    'src/UI/index.ts',
  ],
  output: [
    {
      format: 'cjs',
      dir: 'dist',
      exports: 'auto',
      preserveModules: true,
      preserveModulesRoot: 'src',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    // Preferably set as first plugin.
    peerDepsExternal(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.rollup.json',
    }),
    postcss({
      extract: false,
      modules: true,
      use: ['sass'],
    }),
  ],
};

export default options;
```

**scripts/postinstall.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e;

# skip postinstall if npm install for development
# rollup.config.js is not included in dist
if [ -f "rollup.config.js" ]; then
  echo "skipping your package's postinstall routine.";
  exit 0;
fi

echo 'Copying files from dist folder into root project folder...'
cp -r dist/* ./ && rm -rf dist
echo 'Postinstall done!'
```

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./scripts/postinstall.sh",
  },
```

This will compile and output all files to **dist** folder. The postinstall script will copy all files from **dist** into the root project folder.

Note*: The postinstall script should be skipped when running npm install locally. This is done by checking if **rollup.config.js** exists or not.