# NPM import from subfolder

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to release a NPM package and I am currently looking for a solution to give users the option to use my rollup bundled ES5 code, or use the ES6 version.

I have a subfolder called `lib` where I have a `index.js` and another subfolder inside it called `es6` which also has a `index.js`

In my `package.json` I have specified the main file as `./lib/index.js`

How can I now make it possible to import the ES6 file by using `import * as package from "package/es6"` or is that not possible at all? If not, how would you import it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import from subfolder of npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345257/import-from-subfolder-of-npm-package)